# How to build in AOSP with mount -o remount,rw /system

Tags: android, android-source

I'm currently customizing and building a pixel 3a (sargo).

I want to build without root privileges.

So, when building, I built it as `lunch aosp_sargo-user`

here is my question

I want to use `mount -o remount,rw /system`

As a result of searching, it says that I need to edit the init.rc file, but I don't know where to do it.

If not `init.rc` file, let me know if there is another way.

I don't know what to modify in `init.rc` file

Comment: I think you would need an -eng or a -userdebug build. Then you could probably run adb as root, disable-verity and after reboot run adb root and adb remount. Does this work?

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my question.

I think if you build with ```-eng``` or ```-userdebug``` you can do ```mount -o remount,rw /system``` with ```su``` privileges or as you said.

But i want to build in ```-user``` mode.

Therefore, I wonder how to ```mount -o remount,rw /system``` or ```chmod -R 777 /system``` in ```-user``` mode.